# Creating 3D representation of line shapefile using ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d, network, visualisation

I have a line shapefile of links that build a network. Now I'd like to assign each node (or every end of a line segment) a z-value depending on a certain attribute.

Is it possible to then display this where the nodes (ends of lines) are elevated from the ground level based on the z-value and then make a image from an angle that is not from straight above, but kind of like Google Earth from a self defined angle (e.g. 45°)?

The result should be primarily aesthetically pleasing, and less a scientific communication of the results.

[image: snipet of my shapefile]

Comment: If you wish to ask about alternative software please do that in a separate question but for software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap to try and do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a link](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/extensions/3d-analyst/3d-polyline-features.htm) explaining an ESRI polyline Z features.  Take a free training class on displaying 3D features.  If you are using ArcGIS Desktop 10.c then [ArcScene](https://www.esri.com/training/catalog/57630437851d31e02a43f1f6/3d-visualization-techniques-using-arcgis/) should be installed on your computer that is running ArcMap.  If you are on ArcGIS Pro then the [3D display features](https://learn.arcgis.com/en/projects/create-a-scene/) are built into it.

Comment: thank you! I'm using ArcGIS Pro. I belive this is what I was looking for:) Also, I wasnt aware of "Software Recommendations"